# reregexp_replace 2 parameters

Tags: sql, regexp-replace

Currently using the function to find the ending of the email address 'abc' and replace it with 'xyz':

```
regexp_replace("Current Project Manager Email",'@abc.com','@xyz.com') as "Current Project Manager Email",
```

Is it possible to add in a second parameter to search for like:

```
regexp_replace("Current Project Manager Email",'@abc.com' 
               AND 'abcdef.com,'@xyz.com') as "Current Project Manager Email",
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm Pattern is a regular expression as a string, and it supports "|".

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match?

Comment: a workflow I use only send emails that end in '@xyz.com' whereas the data I'm getting has the emails as '@abc.com' and '@abcdef'.com. Hence when I get an error in the workflow it's cause I have accounted for 'abc' and not 'abcdef'....does that help? Tried regexp_replace("Current Project Manager Email",'@abc.com' | 'abcdef.com,'@xyz.com') as "Current Project Manager Email" and it didnt work

Comment: Fixed it! It was the quotation marks I needed to fix....  regexp_replace("Current Project Manager Email",'(@abc.com)|(@abcdef.com)','@xyz.com') as "Current Project Manager Email"

Answer (score 0):

Here's an Oracle solution. It should help you apply it to your RDBMS.  It captures each part of the match in it's own group which can be referenced later by the shorthand \1 (the number is the order of the group from left to right).  Replace with the captured group, the replace text, the other captured group you want.  Note if you do not save the at sign and the period, they are "consumed" by the regex as they are matched and are not available for replacement.

```
    SQL> SELECT regexp_replace('@abc.com;@abcdef.com','(@)(abc(def)?)(\.)', '\1xyz\4') 
         as "Current Project Manager Email"
    FROM DUAL;

Current Project M
-----------------
@xyz.com;@xyz.com

SQL>
```

Your regex could also look like this where you let the consuming happen and just replace the characters:

```
    SELECT regexp_replace('@abc.com;@abcdef.com', '@(abc(def)?)\.', '@xyz.') as "Current Project Manager Email" 
FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

regexp_replace("Current Project Manager Email",'(@abc.com)|(@abcdef.com)','@xyz.com') as "Current Project Manager Email"